# Trouble with PyTorch's 'ToPILImage'

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torchvision

Why does this not work?

```
import torchvision.transforms.functional as tf
from torchvision import transforms
pic = np.random.randint(0, 255+1, size=28*28).reshape(28, 28)
pic = pic.astype(int)
plt.imshow(pic)
t = transforms.ToPILImage()
t(pic.reshape(28, 28, 1))
# tf.to_pil_image(pic.reshape(28, 28, 1))
```

A beautiful random picture is plotted by matplotlib, but no matter what datatype I chose for my NumPy ndarray, neither `to_pil_image` or `ToPILImage` work as expected.

The docs have this to say:

> Converts a tensor ... ***or a numpy ndarray of shape H x W x C*** to a PIL Image while preserving the value range.
> ...
> If the input has 1 channel, the  `mode`  is determined by the data type **(i.e  `int` ,  `float` ,  `short` )**.

None of these datatypes work except for "short".

Everything else results in:

```
TypeError: Input type int64/float64 is not supported
```

thrown from `torchvision/transforms/functional.py` in `to_pil_image()`.

Further, even though the `short` datatype will work for the stand alone code snippet I provided first, it breaks down when used inside a `transform.Compose()` called from a `Dataset` object's `__getitem__`:

```
choices = transforms.RandomChoice([transforms.RandomAffine(30),
                                   transforms.RandomPerspective()])

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),
                                transforms.RandomApply([choices], 0.5),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])

trainset = MNIST('data/train.csv', transform=transform)
trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

```
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 12917) is killed by signal: Floating point exception.
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 12917) exited unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer worked for me only with the following change:

```
pic = pic.astype('uint8')
```

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/993325dd82567f5d4f28ccb321e3a9a16984d2d8/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#:%7E:text=if%20npimg.dtype,dtype%20%3D%3D%20np.float32%3A) of `to_pil_image`, you can see that only numpy arrays of types `np.{uint8, int16, uint32, float32}` are supported.

Try to cast the picture into `np.uint8`

```
pic = pic.astype(np.uint8)
```

That should work for you